# How does a CVE id work? How they are created ? where we can find the official cve list?

Tags: security, cve, hacker-news-api

I was intrested about the process that happens in cve logging.

I have gone through the following website, but i am having a thought only few details are there. and also want to know is there any official site for them.

https://nvd.nist.gov/

https://www.cvedetails.com/

Need some detailed information about cve process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can find the whole process here: https://www.cve.org/About/Process

Request/update CVE ID:
https://www.cve.org/ResourcesSupport/ReportRequest#RequestCVEID